# Serve static files from a folder inside wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, aurelia

I have following ASP.NET Core project structure:

```
.
├── Controllers
├── Dockerfile
├── Models
├── Program.cs
├── Properties
├── README.md
├── Services
├── Startup.cs
├── Views
├── appsettings.json
├── bundleconfig.json
├── project.json
├── web.config
└── wwwroot
```

Inside `wwwroot`, I have set up an Aurelia project using Aurelia `cli`. It has following structure:

```
.
├── aurelia-app
├── css
├── images
├── js
└── temp.html
```

and my `aurelia-app` has the `index.html` file which I want to serve(when I browse to `localhost:5000`, in a similar way if it was in `wwwroot`)

Here's what my `Startup.cs` configure() method looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        EnableDefaultFiles = true,
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
    });

   app.UseMvc();
}
```

What should I change so that upon loading the base url, it looks for the `index.html` file in `wwwroot/aurelia-app` directory?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the `PhysicalFileProvider` solution, but I get the error `PhysicalFileProvider not found`, how do I add that?

Comment: I am using VSCode, so not sure how to add external dependencies without `nuget`.

Comment: add using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that. This sounds silly, but I am also getting errors on `Path`, `Directory`, and `PathString` objects. What should I add to fix that? I am relatively new to aspnet core.

Comment: `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot/aurelia-app")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
            });` btw, this is what I added now..Dows that look right?

Comment: I think in this case you will get /StaticFiles/index.html probably you need to remove StaticFiles.

Comment: I tried both, but nothing is working. Btw, I got rid of the errors by adding `System.IO` and `aspnetcore.HTTP`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this works or not, but you can try.

```
var options = new DefaultFilesOptions
{
   RequestPath = RequestPath = new PathString("/wwwroot/aurelia-app or /aurelia-app")
};
app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with the default 'index' file of your website than with serving static files. I guess you want to serve *all* the files in `wwwroot`, not just what's inside `wwwroot/aurelia-app`. So scoping your static files middleware to `wwwroot/aurelia-app` won't work.

Your best option is probably to set the default application URL to `http://localhost:5000/aurelia-app/index.html` in your `launchSettings.json` (Project -> Properties -> launchSettings.json):

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/aurelia-app/index.html",
}
```

You should apply such setting in your IIS website or Azure Web App as well.
For example:
[image: Azure Web App settings]

Comment: Makes sense. Yes, I want to serve all files in `wwwroot`. Thanks. So I added the above line in my `launchSettings.json`, and also changed the `launchUrl`, so it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/a/e0AfM). Still, when I browse to `localhost:5000`, I get following: http://imgur.com/a/PgK45